# How to return a pointer as an iterator?

Tags: c++, function, return-value, lvalue

I need to implement iterators, and i don't have time to make nice iterator classes, so i have decided to just return pointers. It is something like this

```
int* begin()
{
    return p;
}
```

But i want them to behave as usual stl iterators

```
*++begin(); // doesn't work because returned pointer isn't l-value

std::vector<int> vi{ 0, 1 };
*++vi.begin(); // works fine

int* p = begin();
*++p;  // works fine as well
```

How can i do this?

Comment: @n.m sorry i'm not allowed to change compiler settings, there are a lot of platforms supported, so some of them may not have such switch. But thank you anyway.

Comment: Well then you have to bite the bullet and write a proper iterator class.

Comment: What do you mean with "behave as usual stl iterators"? They will if the allocated memory range your iterators are pointing to is linear and in one chunk. It's the same with `vector`.

Comment: @Luke I just wrote an example where they will not.

Comment: What if you use `*(++begin())`?

Comment: Not sure what you really think "work" means in the example above. You need to elaborate on your example. It looks like perfectly valid code to me and the first and the last example does the same things. Note that `p` in the `begin()` function is a global variable though, not sure if that is part of the confusion.

Comment: One ways is to return an instance of a struct/class which wraps a pointer and that has a working `operator++` (and presumably other operators you need).   There are other ways, but they are hideously dangerous (in the sense of allowing opportunities for undefined behaviour) so I won't describe them.

Comment: @MatsKindahl I'm not sure the example could be any clearer. It shows an example of when using a plain pointer as an iterator doesn't work in the same way as using a user defined type.

Comment: @Yola - The vector example just *happens* to work because the iterator is a class object. The standard doesn't require this.

Comment: If you're allowed to use Boost, using a Boost.Iterator `iterator_facade` over a raw pointer is pretty much two lines of code for a real iterator class.

Comment: "i don't have time to make nice iterator classes" -- if you don't have time to do it right, when will you have time to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pointers *do* meet the iterator requirements prefectly (a pointer meets even the most-specialised *Random access iterator* requirements). Your problem comes from the fact that in the implementation of the standard library which you're using, the iterators provided by e.g. `std::vector` support more operations than the iterator requirements require.

In other words, the standard does **not** guarantee that `++vi.begin()` will work for a `std::vector` iterator `vi`. It happens to work on your implementation of the standard library, but it's an implementation detail. An iterator which would *not* support that is still a perfectly valid iterator.

So, to answer your question: if you want a quick stand-in for an iterator which will support all iterator operations, you can certainly use a pointer. If you want a quick stand-in for an iterator which will additionally support all the operations your standard library implementation supports in addition to iterator requirements, you might have to roll out your own class.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal iterator is quite easy to whip up using `boost`:

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>

using namespace boost;

struct Int100
{
    int arr[100];

    struct iterator : iterator_facade<iterator,int,forward_traversal_tag>
    {
        iterator( int* p = nullptr ) : p(p) {}
        void increment() { ++p; }
        bool equal(const iterator& other) const { return p == other.p; }
        int& dereference() const { return *p; }
        int* p;
    };

    iterator begin() { return {arr}; }
    iterator end() { return {arr+100}; }

};
```

This supports the `*++begin()` syntax you where looking for.